# getting the url as WebDriver instead of www.google.com

Tags: selenium

While performing the code the Test is getting failed as it is taking the actualtitle as webdriver

it has been made by using iedriver 
a comparision is made to the base url and current url .

```
package newproject;
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverLogLevel;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService;

public class Test1 {

    `public static void main(String[] args`) {

     // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables

     String exePath = "D:\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0\\IEDriverServer.exe";
     InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder serviceBuilder = new 
     InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder(); 

     serviceBuilder.usingAnyFreePort(); // This specifies that sever can pick any available free port to start

     serviceBuilder.usingDriverExecutable(new File(exePath));
     //Tell it where you server exe is 

   serviceBuilder.withLogLevel(InternetExplorerDriverLogLevel.TRACE);//Specifies the log level of the server
     serviceBuilder.withLogFile(new File("D:\\abc\\Documents\\logFile.txt")); //Specify the log file. Change it based on your system

     InternetExplorerDriverService service = serviceBuilder.build(); 

     //Create a driver service and pass it to Internet explorer driver instance


    InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service);


    String baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
    StringBuffer expectedTitle = new StringBuffer("web driver");
    String actualTitle = "";
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");// get the actual value of the title
    actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(actualTitle);

    /*compare the actual title of the page with the expected one and prin the result as "Passed" or "Failed"*/


     if (actualTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(baseUrl) )
                    {
                        System.out.println("Test Passed!");
           } else {
                        System.out.println("Test Failed");
           }


     // exit the program explicitly
                System.exit(0);
   }
```

How to get the page url instead of WebDriver??

Answer (score 1):

I have just verified your code. It is taking the actual title as "**Google**" not **webdriver**.

**This line is incorrect:**

```
if (actualTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(baseUrl) ) {
    System.out.println("Test Passed!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Test Failed");
}
```

You shouldn't compare title with the base URL. A comparison should be between expected title and actual title.